# Running a query if the previous query was successful

Tags: mysql

How to run a query if the previous query was successful
I have this code in a trigger before update

```
IF EXISTS (Select * from hwidban where hwid=new.deviceid) then

    select expire into @expire from hwidban where hwid=new.deviceid;

    IF @expire=0 then 

          set new.bantime=9548106383000;

    ELSE  set new.bantime=@expire*1000;

    END IF;  

    update hwidban set logintry=logintry+1;

END IF;
```

And I want to run this query if the previous code was executed successfully

> SET @s = 'Banned'; SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @s;

I can't use TRANSACTION in a trigger, Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How do you measure "success" in that context?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of

`SELECT @@error_count`

This gives you the count of error during that session , so you may define a variable and store the value before your first block and after it's executing can compare the current value of @@error_count to know if any error has occurred.